# Plotting Longitude and Latitude with Point Weight in Scatter Plot Pandas

Tags: pandas

A question for my assignment says "Plot every latitude and longitude in a scatter plot, with the point weight being their value for “median house value"

My line of code currently is

```
train.plot.scatter(x = 'longitude', y = 'latitude', s = 'median_house_value');
```

Am I approaching this question correctly? I am not quite sure what "point weight" means.

Edit:

After running this code I was met with a scatter plot that looks like this

[image: scatter plot]

Is there something else I should be adding into the scatter plot code to reduce the amount of points?

Comment: `median_house_value` might be too big so that a single point covers all your plot. Do `df.plot.scatter(x='lon',y='lat',s=df['size']/1_000_000)`

Comment: Thank you, I believe that did the trick.